# c# Unit Tests that need a non embedded resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am writing a number of unit tests to test a custom model binder.

The ViewModel has data annotations that reference a resource file(s).

Initially the resources where in App_GlobalResources directory - when binding to the model I would get a file not found error as the resources file was not available to the test project.

A post http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx suggests moving the .rex files to another directory and change the custom tool to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

This appears to get me further but I now have an error

{"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"NameSpace.Address.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"Application.UI\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}

I can make the resource file embedded and this fixes the issue BUT I need to keep the resource file as content.

Is there away to access classes that reference resource files in unit tests?

ViewModel is as follows

```
public class CollectOrderDetails
{
    protected Guid _Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.PersonalDetails), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Form_Title_ErrorRequired")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.PersonalDetails), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Form_FirstName_ErrorRequired")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Honestly, it seems like you've not separated your concerns correctly.  The functionality you're testing should not be tied to the lookup of the resource.  Rather, require that all the information you require be passed in and test that by mocking what you need (that way, you decouple the resources from the test).

Comment: Hi - as much as I agree with separation of concerns I am testing the population of a ViewModel by a custom model binder.

Comment: The dependency of the resource file to the ViewModel is unavoidable - since we are using data annotations (Validation). I am already mocking HttpContext and ControllerContext. Are you suggesting to Mock the ViewModel also?

Comment: var binder = new DateDropdownModelBinder(); 
            var httpContext = MockHelper.FakeHttpContext(HttpVerbs.Post, formCollection);
            var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), new Mock<Controller>().Object);

            // Act
            var result = binder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as CollectOrderDetails;

Comment: How can I inject a Mocked ViewModel in the above scenario? CollectOrderDetails is the ViewModel